# About the relation ship between A driven event and multithreading

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, object

While i was doing [this try it yourself on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout_cleartimeout2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="startCount()">Start count!</button>
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button onclick="stopCount()">Stop count!</button>

<p>
Click on the "Start count!" button above to start the timer. The input field will count forever, starting at 0. Click on the "Stop count!" button to stop the counting. Click on the "Start count!" button to start the timer again.
</p>

<script>
var c = 0;
var t;
var timer_is_on = 0;

function timedCount() {
    document.getElementById("txt").value = c;
    c = c + 1;
    t = setTimeout(function(){ timedCount() }, 1000);
}

function startCount() {
    if (!timer_is_on) {
        timer_is_on = 1;
        timedCount();
    }
}

function stopCount() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    timer_is_on = 0;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I noticed that I had a question deep in me that I had never asked before

In this tutorial, the timedCount() kept calling itself and it will never stop.
and obviously. When you click stop the recursion stops

kindly point the key to me.

I thought the program should have ran for ever, which means that it wont accept any driven event by the button

Thanks.

Comment: What code are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not actually “run forever”, it's just a way of seeing it. Actually, it reschedules itself to run again in 1000 milliseconds.

But when clicking the button, `stopCount` is called, which discards the current rescheduling (`clearTimeout(t);`)